# folder structure in the remote git repos

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm trying to add obfuscation tool to my Azure DevOps build process. The vendor doesn't have extension for their professional edition, so I was advised to add their binaries to the source code repository and then create Win Batch or PowerShell task to run it in the build pipeline.

I got this workaround to work on my local test machine and now trying to setup DevOps. But I ran into issue with the directory structure on my remote repository. In the local repository 
[image: Local repo screenshot]

the folders contain bunch of files, lots of them are binaries, dll, etc....

But here is what I see in the Azure devops:

[image: Remote git repo]

I probably have to tweak some setting somewhere.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe I had this problem before, and fixed it by adding a dummy readme file to each folder on each level. But there has to be a better answer to this.

Comment: If the folders are empty, why do you need them?

Comment: Most likely, your intermediate folders contain no files. That's just how it gets displayed.

Comment: Mad Physicist correct. I don't have empty folders in the file structure. Just some folders only contain folders, which contains folders, which contains files. I would really hate to start creating dummy files in the intermediate folders. Another thing is that forward slash is illegal character for windows system. Looks like Devops using Linux system to store Git repos.